# Suppress alphabetical sorting of fields in Mongo query response (using Flask to wirte APIs to work with Mongo)

Tags: mongodb, flask

I am writing a query to fetch data from a collection for a particular user

```
for field in db.full_mock_data.find({'user': user}):
        output.append({'testName': field['testName'], 
                        'user': field['user'], 
                        'testDate': field['testDate'],
.
.
.
so on
```

However the response is sorted in alphabetical order of fields.

I understand that I can set the column defs in the order desired. However I was wondering if there is a way of suppressing the sorting from the query itself as this would save me the trouble of setting column defs manually as there are close to 50 fields.

Comment: `Suppress alphabetical sorting of fields` is very unclear, could you explain more and give few examples?

Comment: In the db:
{
b: abc,
c: xyz,
a: pqr
}

in the query response:
{
a: pqr,
b: abc,
c: xyz
}

I want to preserve the order of fields.